# How to optimize render() in React when prop is an object?

Tags: reactjs

Imagine a `List` component that renders a list of items, and optionally highlights one of them.

[image]

`List` has the following props:

- `items` - items to display
- `highlightedItemIndex` - the index of the highlighted item (or `null`, if none is highlighted)
- `itemProps` - arbitrary props object to pass through to every item

`List`'s `render()` method looks like this:

```javascript
<ul>
  {
    items.map((item, index) => {
      const allItemProps = {
        ...itemProps,
        className: index === highlightedItemIndex ? 'highlighted-item' : ''
      };

      return (
        <Item item={item} itemProps={allItemProps} key={index} />
      );
    })
  }
</ul>
```

The problem is, that every time `List`'s `render()` is called, `Item` gets a new object for `itemProps` causing `Item`'s `render()` to be called, which is unnecessary most of the times because `itemProps` didn't really change (it deep equals to the previous `itemProps`, but not `===`).

Imagine the image above with 1000 items, and as you hover the items, the highlighted item changes accordingly. Every time the highlighted item is changing, `Item`'s `render()` should be called twice, not 1000 times!

Adding:

```javascript
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  return JSON.stringify(nextProps) !== JSON.stringify(this.props);
}
```

solves the issue, but I feel like the `JSON.stringify` approach can be quite expensive.

[Here is a playground](http://codepen.io/moroshko/pen/bZrERy?editors=0010) I created to demonstrate the issue. (I have 5 items in the list rather than 1000, but you get the idea.)

What's the "React way" to optimise rendering when a prop is an object (`inputProps` in this case), or maybe object props is not a good practice?

Comment: The best would be to make sure that `item` is the same object. I think it is most of the time possible.

Comment: In your example, it looks like you may avoid using the `allItemsProps`. Maybe it could be the responsibility of the `Item` to know what class to have when highlighted and the `highlight` may be a property of the item.

Comment: maybe lodash isEqual feets for you http://www.webpackbin.com/VkbwSLhPW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for sharing a CodePen – that helped a lot with working on an answer.

I've updated your pen a bit, so it only renders as necessary: http://codepen.io/amann/pen/dXZpyz?editors=0010

There's some copy-pasted code from the PureRenderMixin at the top, please scroll down until you see `Relevant code starts here`.

Here are the most relevant parts:

```
class Item extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onMouseEnter = this.onMouseEnter.bind(this);
    this.shouldComponentUpdate = PureRenderMixin.shouldComponentUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  onMouseEnter() {
    this.props.onMouseEnter(this.props.index);
  }

  render() {
    const { item, isHighlighted } = this.props;

    itemRenderCounter++;

    let className = 'item';
    if (isHighlighted) className += ' highlighted-item';

    return (
      <li className={className} onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter}>
        {item}
      </li>
    );
  }
}

class List extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    items: []
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onMouseLeave = this.onMouseLeave.bind(this);
    this.onItemMouseEnter = this.onItemMouseEnter.bind(this);
  }

  onMouseLeave() {
    this.props.onHighlightedItemChange(null);
  }

  onItemMouseEnter(index) {
    this.props.onHighlightedItemChange(index);
  }

  render() {
    const { items, highlightedItemIndex, onHighlightedItemChange} = this.props;

    return (
      <ul className="list-container" onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}>
        {items.map((item, index) =>
          <Item
            key={index}
            index={index}
            item={item}
            isHighlighted={index === highlightedItemIndex}
            onMouseEnter={this.onItemMouseEnter}
          />
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {highlightedItemIndex: 1};
    this.onHighlightedItemChange = this.onHighlightedItemChange.bind(this);
  }

  onHighlightedItemChange(index) {
    this.setState({highlightedItemIndex: index});
  }

  render() {
    const { highlightedItemIndex } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <List
          items={fruits}
          highlightedItemIndex={highlightedItemIndex}
          onHighlightedItemChange={this.onHighlightedItemChange}
        />
        <div className="counter">
          Item render() counter: {itemRenderCounter}
        </div>
      </div>
     );
  }
}
```

I think your initial problem could be solved by using the spread operator `<Item {...itemProps} .../>`. That way a shallow compare becomes possible on the Item level. However, I thought there are some other things that could be improved, so I changed a bit more.

Some notes:

- Default props are usually done better with `static defaultProps = {…}` instead of a default assignment when destructuring in the render method.
- The `App` component probably shouldn't be concerned with mouse events, but rather provide some more semantic callbacks like `onHighlightedItemChange`. Depending on your use case you could also think about moving the state which list item is highlighted to `List`.
- I think it makes sense that `Item` manages its own class name, as long as the parent component isn't overriding some styles. Therefore I computed its class name from the semantic property `isHighlighted`. Maybe `isHighlighted` could also be used for some other differences, independent of the class name, in the future.
- We could also do `<Item onMouseEnter={this.props.onHighlightedItemChange.bind(null, index)} />` in the render method of `List`. This is somewhat common, as the child component doesn't have to know about its `index`. However in your case, as performance seems to be a concern, it's better to not that, since the `bind` call will create a new function on every render, thus always requiring a re-render in the comparison of `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Hope this helps!

If you're going to use my code, make sure to use the npm package of [react-addons-pure-render-mixin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-addons-pure-render-mixin) instead of my copy pasted code. Btw. there's probably soon gonna be a `React.PureComponent` that will implement `shouldComponentUpdate` by default – this will come in handy for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You got the right idea. Just target the value that really defines this situation

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  return nextProps.itemProps.className !== this.props.itemProps.className;
}
```

Comment: User can provide arbitrary item props that should be taken into consideration when rendering. For example, you could have `itemProps.title` that is changing and needs to be reflected by rerendering. If you just check `inputProps.className`, and `inputProps.title` changes, the UI won't update, which is not good.

Comment: You're right and I didn't take consideration of that.

In shouldComponentUpdate I will explicitly define which itemProps' values to consider. I personally would only go with your `JSON.stringify` way if itemProps is huge and all itemProps values would affect **rendering**.